# CSS3 crossfade simialr to setinterval

Tags: css, transition, fade

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to the JS setinterval/settimeout but using CSS3.  So far I have achieved the desired effect, but only with :hover.  How can I have this work so that the animation will just run every 3-4 seconds, without the need to hover?

Consider:

```
<div id="crossfade">
    <img class="bottom" src="http://www.boohoo.com/content/ebiz/boohoo/resources/images    /topbanners/Offer_Strip_GBP_v1.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="http://www.boohoo.com/content/ebiz/boohoo/resources/images/topbanners/Offer_Strip_EUR_v1.jpg" />
</div>
```

And:

```
#crossfade {
    position:relative;
    height:250px;
    width:400px;
}
#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
#crossfade img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEwPb/

Comment: You can use [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?  Or showing an example? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qEwPb/3/

Comment: That just seems to be flashing on and off for me :(

Comment: Sorry, should be http://jsfiddle.net/qEwPb/4/

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you, do you want to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

You can use CSS3 [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)

[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qEwPb/4/)

```css
#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#crossfade img.top {
    -webkit-animation-name:pulse;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
    -webkit-animation-direction:alternate;

    animation-name:pulse;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-direction:alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

[Browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)

Adjust `animation-duration` to fit your need.

Edit:

If you want to stay at e.g. transparent for a few seconds, use something like this:

```css
img.top {
    animation-duration:5s;
}
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having now, demonstrated in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qEwPb/6/
is that the animation only stays on the second image for a second, before changing again.. any suggestions?

Comment: @Myles How long do you want to stay at the top, and the bottom? Right now your fiddle uses 5s to transact, 1s from top to bottom (0%-20%), stay at bottom for 4s (20%-100%), and go back. You can adjust the animation duration and percentage in keyframes to fit your need.

Comment: I've sorted it, thanks :)  Ended up using jQuery, as I needed this to work on ALL browsers and platforms, including older versions of IE.

http://jsfiddle.net/ezR8h/